# clearing session values saved from a http handler file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, httphandler

I am working on a http handler file where I am setting some session values,

I am unable to clear these sessions on logout button(on a different page).

- My logout button is on master page.
- I am not saving session values in cookies.

I am using below interface in handler file :-

```
public class abc : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```

Handler file setting session value:-

```
context.Session["CheckInId"] = 1;
```

Logout button's code:-

```
protected void lbtnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            Session.Clear();
            Session.RemoveAll();           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {           
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of `SessionState` are you using? Also, don't put everything inside `try { ... } catch { ... }`, because doing that just makes it difficult to find out what goes wrong. Finally, *how* do you know that you are *unable to clear these sessions*? `Session.Abandon();` really should be all you need here...

Comment: i am checking on the same master page ..